# Python: nested list merge with adding int in same index

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, dataframe

I simply want to add two list just like below. I do not have to use nested list, but it can be changed to numpy array. Please let me know. Thanks!

```
input
lst1 = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
lst2 = [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]

output
lst = [[1,1,1],[2,0,1],[1,1,1]]
```

I have tried to add with simple "+" or merge, but it seems like it would not work like Pandas DataFrame where you can do same function with '+'. I am not willing to use DataFrame, but make it simple as list or array.

Also if this can be done without using loops, it would be perfect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With numpy:

```
np.add(lst1, lst2).tolist()

# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

If you want it fast and are ok with `numpy` arrays instead of list of lists leave out the `.tolist()`:

```
np.add(lst1, lst2)

# array([[1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 0, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1]])
```

As soon as your list of lists are all converted to arrays you can simply write `+`, indeed it suffices if one of the two terms is an array:

```
lst1 + np.array(lst2)

# array([[1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 0, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: This is perfect! Do you think this would work faster then using loops? I am trying to minimize the run time

Comment: The addition itself is fast, but this is converting from list to array and back which is not optimal speed-wise. If you can, stay with arrays!

Answer (score 3):

Two levels deep = double comprehension! :)

```
[[x + y for x, y in zip(sublst1, sublst2)] for sublst1, sublst2 in zip(lst1, lst2)]
```

EDIT: or, shorter (thanks to Stefan Pochmann):

```
[[x + y for x, y in zip(*sublists)] for sublists in zip(lst1, lst2)]
```

Comment: Can it be done without using loops? I am trying to minimize the process time by avoiding loops.

Comment: No. You can have loops in Python (`for`) like in Mahesh's answer, you can have implicit loops made by comprehensions as in my answer, or you can have implicit loops in numpy as in Paul's answer. The only way to not have loops is to parallelise it using dedicated parallel hardware (for example, using CUDA on GPU). However, if your time is really critical, benchmark it - premature optimisation is the root of all evil, as Knuth says.

Comment: `[[x + y for x, y in zip(*sublists)] for sublists in zip(lst1, lst2)]`

Answer (score 3):

You keep asking, can you do it faster without loops?  Have you done any timings?

```
In [225]: lst1 = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
     ...: lst2 = [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]
     ...: 
In [226]: np.add(lst1,lst2).tolist()
Out[226]: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

In [227]: timeit np.add(lst1,lst2).tolist()
12 µs ± 20.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [228]: [[i+j for i,j in zip(a,b)] for a,b in zip(lst1,lst2)]
Out[228]: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
In [229]: timeit [[i+j for i,j in zip(a,b)] for a,b in zip(lst1,lst2)]
4.88 µs ± 1.05 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For this example, the loops version is faster than the array version.  That's because creating arrays from the lists takes time.  `np.add` has to convert list arguments to arrays before doing the addition.

The pure array version:

```
In [230]: %%timeit a,b = np.array(lst1), np.array(lst2)
     ...: np.add(a,b)
     ...: 
794 ns ± 10.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

With much larger lists the relative timings might differ - but when I've tested this sort of thing in the past, list operations remain faster for quite a range of sizes.

Comment: Very illuminating! Thanks.

Comment: If you are doing just the one sum, sure. But that doesn't strike me as a common use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1 = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
lst2 = [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]

result = []
for l1, l2 in zip(lst1, lst2):
    result.append([x+y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)])

print(result)
```

Comment: Can it be done without using loops? I am trying to minimize the process time by avoiding loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can created own function as follows:

```
def list_add(list1, list2):
    res_list = []
    for each_item1, each_item2 in zip(list1, list2):
        new_list = []
        for each_ele1, each_ele2 in zip(each_item1, each_item2):
            new_list.append(each_ele1 + each_ele2)
        res_list.append(new_list)
    return res_list

lst1 = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
lst2 = [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]

print(list_add(lst1, lst2))
```

**output:**

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Can it be done without using loops? I am trying to minimize the process time by avoiding loops.

Answer (score 1):

A nested `lambda(map(...)` requires no loops:

```
lst1 = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
lst2 = [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]

result = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y[0] + y[1], zip(*x))), zip(lst1, lst2)))

print(result)
# [[1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Although its a lot slower compared to the list comprehension suggested by @Amaden:

```
In [1]: lst1 = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]

In [2]: lst2 = [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]

In [3]: timeit list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y[0] + y[1], zip(*x))), zip(lst1, lst2)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.78 µs per loop

In [4]: timeit [[x + y for x, y in zip(*sublists)] for sublists in zip(lst1, lst2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.92 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

although it has been answered already , I did it like below with help of numpy

```
import numpy as np
list1=[[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
list2 = [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]

arr1=np.array((list1)) #Convert list to 2darray
arr2=np.array((list2)) #convert list to 2d array 

arr1+arr2   # simply adds the 2d array
```

output :

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this if you want in one line :

```
lst1 = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
lst2 = [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,1]]

print(list(map(lambda x,y:(list(map(lambda y,z:(y+z),x,y))),lst1,lst2)))
```

output:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```